# Pulseaudio HFP configuration

Tags: embedded-linux, pulseaudio, hfp

I'm trying to develop HFP devices using an embedded board and a bluetooth USB dongle. I'm using Bluez 5.52, Pulseaudio 13.0, Ofono 1.31.

The A2DP profile works well streaming audio from my phone to the audio jack of the embedded device. The HFP has problems. During a call, automatically started using OfonoVcm from a Qt program, **I only hear sound from the speaker but no voice arrives to the remote phone.**

Prior to starting a call I activate the "headset_audio_gateway" profile by programatically calling: "pactl set-card-profile 2 headset_audio_gateway".

**How to setup pulseaudio .pa and .conf files for this?**

Below my sinks and sources list prior to call:

> pactl list sources short
>   0 alsa_output.hw_0_0.monitor module-alsa-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
>   1 alsa_input.hw_0_0       module-alsa-source.c    s16le 2ch 44100Hz SUSPENDED 
>   2 alsa_output.2.stereo-fallback.monitor module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>   3 alsa_output.1.stereo-fallback.monitor   module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>   4 alsa_input.1.stereo-fallback module-alsa-card.c      s24-32le 2ch 44100Hz    SUSPENDED
>   5 alsa_output.0.stereo-fallback.monitor   module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>   6 alsa_input.0.stereo-fallback module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>   pactl list sinks short
>   0 alsa_output.hw_0_0      module-alsa-sink.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>   1 alsa_output.2.stereo-fallback   module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>   2 alsa_output.1.stereo-fallback module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch 44100Hz       SUSPENDED
>   3 alsa_output.0.stereo-fallback   module-alsa-card.c      s16le 2ch  44100Hz       SUSPENDED

Let me know if you need further information related to my actual .pa and .conf Pulseaudio configuration.

Kind regards,

Matteo

Answer (score 1):

The proble was in the audio card. Using an usb audio card everything works...

Cheers,

Matteo